# 3D点群からの体積算出

Tags: c++, c

3Dカメラから取得した三次元点群から物体の体積を求めたいのですが、PCLを使うなどして簡単に求めることは可能でしょうか？
PCLに限らず求める方法や参考となるサイトなどご存じでしたらご教示くたさい、

Comment: PCLユーザフォーラムに[関連スレッド](http://www.pcl-users.org/Approximate-volume-estimate-from-octree-td4038388.html)があるようです。